# How to get an HTTP Proxy response Header in Golang built-in HTTP client?

Tags: http, go, debugging, networking, proxy

I'm doing a simple HTTP GET request with the default `net/http` Golang lib via HTTP proxy and want to read the content of the first proxy reply(for the HTTP client req with the CONNECT method).

In plain text, it looks like this

[image]

```http
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Request-Uid: <some id>
<another header>: <another value>
```

Golang code:

```golang
...
proxyUrlParsed, errUrl := url.Parse(proxyUrl)
tr := &http.Transport{
   Proxy:   http.ProxyURL(proxyUrlParsed),
}
client := &http.Client{
   Transport: tr,
}
request, errReq := http.NewRequest("GET", targetUrl, nil)
response, errDo := client.Do(request)
// Response contains HTTP headers from the reply from the 
// target resource but not the intermediate proxy.
```

I partially solved it with DialContext, but I were needed to impl some parts of the protocol that I found not so handy and costly for later support. So is there an easy and clever way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

## tunnel proxy

Take the use of the curl client as an example. When requesting https, use the `CONNECT` method to connect to the tunnel connection. The obtained stream content is TLS encrypted content, which cannot be decrypted by the proxy.

If have a tls certificate, can try to parse the response stream.

When `wireshark` captures https requests, a parameter needs to be configured in the browser. The certificate is saved in the specified file

```bash
http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8021 https_proxy=127.0.0.1:8021 curl -v https://qq.com
http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8021 https_proxy=127.0.0.1:8021 curl -v https://qq.com
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    proxy := func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        log.Println("proxy", req.Method, req.RequestURI)
        if req.URL.Host != "" {
            if req.Method == http.MethodConnect {
                // tunnel
                conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", req.URL.Host)
                if err != nil {
                    w.WriteHeader(502)
                    fmt.Fprint(w, err)
                    return
                }

                client, _, err := w.(http.Hijacker).Hijack()
                if err != nil {
                    w.WriteHeader(502)
                    fmt.Fprint(w, err)
                    conn.Close()
                    return
                }
                client.Write([]byte("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n"))

                hr, hw := io.Pipe()
                go func(){
                    io.Copy(os.Stdout, hr)
                    hr.Close()
                }()
                go func() {
                    // print response to stdout
                    io.Copy(io.MultiWriter(client, hw), conn)
                    client.Close()
                    conn.Close()
                    hw.Close()
                }()
                go func() {
                    io.Copy(conn, client)
                    client.Close()
                    conn.Close()
                }()
                return
            }

            httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(req.URL).ServeHTTP(w, req)
        }
    }
    http.ListenAndServe(":8021", http.HandlerFunc(proxy))
}
```

## reverse proxy

use [`/net/http/httputil.ReverseProxy`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httputil#ReverseProxy) proxy a request ,set `ModifyResponse` field is response hook.

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(&url.URL{
                                                Scheme: "http", 
                                                Host: "127.0.0.1:8020"})

    proxy.ModifyResponse = func(w *http.Response) error {
        w.Header.Add("Author", "eudore")
        log.Println(w.Request.Method, w.Request.RequestURI, w.Status)
        return nil
    }
    http.ListenAndServe(":8021", proxy)
}
```

#### Curl requests

With port 8020 like `[root@node1 ~]# curl -I  127.0.0.1:8020?222`

```http
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Www-Authenticate: Basic
Date: Thu, 17 Nov 2022 01:34:06 GMT
```

Or port 8021 like `[root@node1 ~]# curl -I  127.0.0.1:8021?222`

```http
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Author: eudore
Date: Thu, 17 Nov 2022 01:34:07 GMT
Www-Authenticate: Basic
```

Comment: I'm talking about forward proxies (or tunnel, or gateway), not reverse proxies. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling

Thanks for your reply, but it's irrelevant to my case.

Comment: @greggyNapalm  Add tunnel proxy content.

Comment: I've added the screenshot of the typical plain-text interaction with the generic HTTP proxy service. As you can see, the first reply is pliant-text and can be read by the client. After the successful proxy reply, the interaction with the target resource will take place, and it might be increased, like in my case b/c of the 443 port == TLS protocol.

Answer (score 0):

In Golang >=1.20 this task can be solved using standard library https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@master#Transport.OnProxyConnectResponse

Code example https://github.com/greggyNapalm/proxychick/blob/v0.0.1/pkg/httpx/httpx.go#L116